# Cannot see sudhi token in wallet on polygon

Tags: polygon, sushiswap

I made swap on sushiswap on polygon. I cant find it in my wallet.
Here is the transaction:
https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x7e9ddfd769fece10898b2bebd76f75146cdeb34aa7450f8084e1a53cb786b45c
I cant figure out what happens in that transaction.
someone can help please? :)

Comment: The transaction you have shared is of `approve` not the `swap`. Can you check again?